# module to change view field value in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to write php code to change my view's field value. I have a php template file, under the theme, and the code is like:

```
$view = views_get_view_result("gallery");
$count = count($view);
if ($count>=1) {
  $ids = explode(",", $view[0]->nextag_items_tags);
  $tagword = "";
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
      $query = db_select('nextag_words', 'a');
      $query->fields('a', array('tagword'));
      $query->condition('a.id', $id, '=');
      $results = $query->execute()->fetchField();
      $tagword .= $results . ",";
  }
  $view[0]->nextag_words_tagword = $tagword; 
  //?????? My question is here
}
```

My question is how can I set the new field value to the drupal view, so that display would change? This has bother me for a long time...

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: You should move this question to drupal.stackexchange.com - it will get you better responses.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need change view field display only? Use preprocess functions or views hooks like [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).